# CSS - Buttons not Aligning

Tags: html, css

I am having an issue with getting buttons to line up correctly for my webpage.

So far, this is what I have:

[image: http://img17.imageshack.us/img17/2209/capturekxh.png]

```
<div class="containerBoxes">                                        
   <div class="search">
       <form id="search-form" action="search.aspx" method="GET" accept-charset="utf-8" class="navbar-form" style="height:35px; width:100%" >
       <input type="text" name="s" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value=''" onfocus="if(this.value =='' ) this.value=''"  />
       <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('search-form').submit()"></a>
       </form>
   </div>


   <form id="Form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="scrpMngMaster" runat="server">
        <Scripts>
          <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/js/jquery.js"/>
          <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"/>
          <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/js/camera.js"/>
          <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/js/jquery.ui.totop.js"/>
          <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/search/search.js"/>                        
          <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/js/google.js"/>
          <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/js/livechat.js"/>  
          <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/js/bootstrap.js"/>  
        </Scripts>
        </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>    

  <div class="newsletter">                               
    <input type="text" runat="server" id="inputNewsletterEmail" onfocus="if(this.value =='Newsletter Sign Up - Enter Email' ) this.value=''" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Newsletter Sign Up - Enter Email'" value="Newsletter Sign Up - Enter Email" style="background-color:#232323; width:95%;" />
    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator  
        ID="regEmail"
        ControlToValidate="inputNewsletterEmail"
        Text="(Invalid email)"
        ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*"
        Runat="server" />
        <asp:Button id="btnNewsletter" runat="server" class="btn btn_" Text="subscribe" OnClick="btnNewsletter_OnClick" />
        <asp:Label ID="lblSuccess" runat="server" Visible="false" ForeColor="#97D816" Font-Bold="true" Font-Size="12px"></asp:Label>
   </div>


 </form>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.containerBoxes
{
  float:right;
}
```

The issue I am having is that the 'submit button' still does not line up with the newsletter text field.  Any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: Tip: Don't use TABLEs for layouts, learn how to use CSS.

Comment: I am not certain how to make it work in jsfiddle.net as I've never used it.  I forgot to mention (and it's probably pretty important) that this is a master page that I am working on, so I'm not sure if that has something to do with jsfiddle not working the way I would expect.  http://jsfiddle.net/photogal57/HKaaJ/5/embedded/result/

Comment: The form `search-form` is too small for the search image to be on the same line. In Chrome I had to set a width of at least `340px` before they showed up on the same line.

Comment: You were right!  Thanks for the tip on that.  It appears that the search box is now working correctly in all browsers.  =)  Now if only I could get the 'subscribe' button to be on the same line as the newsletter, that would be great!

Comment: No one will be able to help you further without a jsfiddle or some code to work with.

Comment: I will have jsfiddle updated with a generic template to see what can be manipulated.  Thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 0):

As said before, don't use tables for your layout, the only time when you need to use `table` is when you want a table (makes sense, no?) What you need is this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="search">
    <input type="text" />
    <img src="glass.png" />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.search{
    position:relative;
}
input{
    padding-left:30px;
}
img{
    position:absolute;
    top:5px; /* adjust value so it looks right */
    left:300px; /* adjust value so it looks right */
    z-index:100;
}
```

Edit: OP changed his original question, I'll leave this up here for anyone who's looking for a solution to insert the magifiying glass inside the text field.

Comment: @MiniRagnarok Not using tables was just a tip, obviously not required to make the code above work.

Comment: I've updated the use of tables in the master page only.  Any other formatting issues is an issue for another day.  Above, I have posted any changes I have made using <div> tags and the bit of css I wrote to try formatting these elements.  So far, it appears only the 'submit' button the newsletter field is off.  Any ideas?  And thanks again.

Comment: @MiniRagnarok  What you saw was not what I have been testing.  By the way, would it be too much to ask you to remove the link to my website in your previous comment?